# making a button to hover

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

The thing that I have to do is that when I press the button it should hower to the RIGHT, till it reached the label's left side. In my case the button just dissapears. What might be the solution?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < label1.Left; i++)
    {
        button1.Left += i;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it WPF ?? Winforms ???

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Left < label1.Left)
        {
            button1.Left++;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When the timer ticks, it will loop the for-loop once (that call of the timer1_Tick) and moves it to ((button1.Left + label1.Left) * numberOfTicks).
The code you have is pretty much the same as just writing:

```
button1_Click(object s, EventArgs e){
  timer1.Tick += delegate(object sender, EventArgs ev){
    button1.Left += label1.Left;
  };
  timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

If you want to move it like that using a timer, you will have to set an interval, and every time the timer ticks, move it a few pixels, not all pixels.

---

Something like:

```
const int DISTANCE = 1;

void button1_Click(object s, EventArgs e){
  timer1.Enabled = true;
}

void timer1_Tick(object s, EventArgs e){
  if(button1.Left < label1.Left)      
    button1.Left += DISTANCE;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the code he has written will move the button to the square of the distance to the label or something (+= i in a for-loop that goes all the way to label.Left)

Comment: Ah yes, like "button1.Left += label1.Left" instead of "button1.Left = label1.Left". Edited answer. :)

Comment: Actually it is a lot more than that as well. lets say that Label1.Left is 5, then for each time the timer triggers, it adds 0+1+2+3+4 = 10.
if it was 10, it would be 0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 45. etc...

Comment: Oh yes, didn't even think of that! :)